# SDHC card is read as SD by READ_OCR

Tags: spi, memory, sd

I'm trying to use 32 GiB SDHC card in SPI mode but I have problem with initialization. I send SD_SEND_OP which finally returned 0x00 but it doesn't have CCS bit set:

```
INFO Initial SD: inserted
└─ src/sd.rs:616
INFO SD inserted
└─ src/sd.rs:622
INFO Waiting for voltage to settle
└─ src/sd.rs:596
INFO Putting SD into SPI mode
└─ src/sd.rs:598
INFO Attempting to reset
└─ src/sd.rs:507
INFO Sending command: [40, 00, 00, 00, 00, 95]
└─ src/sd.rs:474
INFO Still no response
└─ src/sd.rs:490
INFO Got response: [01]
└─ src/sd.rs:493
INFO Reset
└─ src/sd.rs:516
INFO Sending voltage selection
└─ src/sd.rs:523
INFO Sending command: [48, 00, 00, 01, aa, 87]
└─ src/sd.rs:474
INFO Still no response
└─ src/sd.rs:490
INFO Got response: [01, 00, 00, 01, aa]
└─ src/sd.rs:493
INFO Decoded response as R7 { command_version: 0, voltage_accepted: Some(Voltage3v3), pattern: 170 }
└─ src/sd.rs:530
INFO Reading OCR
└─ src/sd.rs:541
INFO Sending command: [7a, 00, 00, 00, 00, fd]
└─ src/sd.rs:474
INFO Still no response
└─ src/sd.rs:490
INFO Got response: [01, 00, ff, 80, 00]
└─ src/sd.rs:493
INFO OCR decoded as R3 { 3V55 3V45 3V35 3V25 3V15 3V05 2V95 2V85 2V75 }
└─ src/sd.rs:543
INFO Sending operation condition
└─ src/sd.rs:562
INFO Sending command: [77, 00, 00, 00, 00, 65]
└─ src/sd.rs:474
INFO Still no response
└─ src/sd.rs:490
INFO Got response: [01]
└─ src/sd.rs:493
INFO Sending command: [69, 40, 00, 00, 00, 77]
└─ src/sd.rs:474
INFO Still no response
└─ src/sd.rs:490
INFO Got response: [01]
└─ src/sd.rs:493
INFO Still idle
└─ src/sd.rs:569
INFO Sending operation condition
└─ src/sd.rs:562
INFO Sending command: [77, 00, 00, 00, 00, 65]
└─ src/sd.rs:474
INFO Still no response
└─ src/sd.rs:490
INFO Got response: [01]
└─ src/sd.rs:493
INFO Sending command: [69, 40, 00, 00, 00, 77]
└─ src/sd.rs:474
INFO Still no response
└─ src/sd.rs:490
INFO Got response: [01]
└─ src/sd.rs:493
INFO Still idle
(...)
INFO Sending command: [77, 00, 00, 00, 00, 65]
└─ src/sd.rs:474
INFO Still no response
└─ src/sd.rs:490
INFO Got response: [01]
└─ src/sd.rs:493
INFO Sending command: [69, 40, 00, 00, 00, 77]
└─ src/sd.rs:474
INFO Still no response
└─ src/sd.rs:490
INFO Got response: [00]
└─ src/sd.rs:493
INFO Reading OCR
└─ src/sd.rs:582
INFO Sending command: [7a, 00, 00, 00, 00, fd]
└─ src/sd.rs:474
INFO Still no response
└─ src/sd.rs:490
INFO Got response: [00, 80, ff, 80, 00]
└─ src/sd.rs:493
INFO OCR decoded as R3 { BUSY 3V55 3V45 3V35 3V25 3V15 3V05 2V95 2V85 2V75 }
└─ src/sd.rs:584
```

The code is:

```rust
    async fn send_command<C: Command>(&mut self, argument: C::Argument, expect_idle: Option<bool>, mut timeout: Option<u32>) -> Result<C::Response, Error>
    where
        [u8; C::Response::LENGTH]: Sized
    {
        const COMMAND_OFFSET: usize = 8;
        const COMMAND_LEN: usize = 6;
        self.cs.set_low();
        let mut command_buffer = [0xFF; COMMAND_OFFSET + COMMAND_LEN];
        let command = &mut command_buffer[COMMAND_OFFSET..COMMAND_OFFSET + COMMAND_LEN];
        command[0] = C::CODE;
        let argument: [u8; 4] = argument.into();
        command[1..5].copy_from_slice(&argument);
        let mut digest = CRC.digest();
        digest.update(&command[0..5]);
        command[5] = (digest.finalize() << 1) | 1;
        defmt::info!("Sending command: {:02x}", command);
        self.spi.write(&command_buffer).await?;
        let mut response_buffer = [0xFFu8; C::Response::LENGTH];
        loop {
            if let Some(ref mut timeout) = timeout {
                if *timeout == 0 {
                    defmt::error!("Timeout on command");
                    return Err(Error::Timeout);
                }
                *timeout -= 1;
            }
            
            self.spi.transfer_in_place(&mut response_buffer[0..1]).await?;
            if response_buffer[0] != 0xFF {
                break;
            }
            defmt::info!("Still no response");
        }
        self.spi.transfer_in_place(&mut response_buffer[1..]).await?;
        defmt::info!("Got response: {:02x}", response_buffer);
        self.cs.set_high();
        <C::Response as Response>::from(response_buffer, expect_idle)
    }

    async fn spi_wait(&mut self, cycles: u32) -> Result<(), Error> {
        for _ in 0..cycles {
            self.spi.write(&[0xFF]).await?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    async fn reset(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        loop {
            defmt::info!("Attempting to reset");
            match self.send_command::<GoIdleState>(ZeroArgument, Some(true), Some(8)).await {
                Ok(R1) => {
                    break;
                }
                Err(Error::Timeout) => {},
                Err(e) => Err(e)?
            }
        }
        defmt::info!("Reset");
        Ok(())
    }

    async fn select_voltage(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        const CHECK_PATTERN: u8 = 0xAA;
        const VOLTAGE: SendIfCondVoltage = SendIfCondVoltage::Voltage3v3;
        defmt::info!("Sending voltage selection");
        let arg = SendIfCondArgument {
            check_pattern: CHECK_PATTERN,
            voltage: VOLTAGE,
            ..Default::default()
        };
        let response = self.send_command::<SendIfCond>(arg, Some(true), Some(8)).await?;
        defmt::info!("Decoded response as {}", response);
        if response.pattern != CHECK_PATTERN {
            Err(Error::CheckPatternMismatch { expected: CHECK_PATTERN, got: response.pattern })?;
        }
        if response.voltage_accepted.map_or(true, |voltage| voltage != VOLTAGE) {
            Err(Error::Voltage { expected: VOLTAGE, got: response.voltage_accepted })?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    async fn read_ocr_and_check_voltage(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        defmt::info!("Reading OCR");
        let response = self.send_command::<ReadOcr>(ZeroArgument, Some(true), Some(8)).await?;
        defmt::info!("OCR decoded as {}", response);
        if !response.get_voltage_3v1_3v2() {
            defmt::error!("Card does not support 3.1-3.2V");
            Err(Error::DoesNotAcceptVoltageRange)?;
        }
        if !response.get_voltage_3v2_3v3() {
            defmt::error!("Card does not support 3.2-3.3V");
            Err(Error::DoesNotAcceptVoltageRange)?;
        }
        if !response.get_voltage_3v3_3v4() {
            defmt::error!("Card does not support 3.3-3.4V");
            Err(Error::DoesNotAcceptVoltageRange)?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    async fn send_operation_condition(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        const TIMEOUT: usize = 256;
        for _ in 0..TIMEOUT {
            defmt::info!("Sending operation condition");
            let R1 = self.send_command::<AppCmd>(ZeroArgument, None, Some(8)).await?;
            let mut argument = SdSendOpCondArg(0);
            argument.set_hcs(true);
            match self.send_command::<SdSendOpCond>(argument, Some(false), Some(8)).await {
                Ok(R1) => return Ok(()),
                Err(Error::Status(status)) if status == Status::IDLE => {
                    defmt::info!("Still idle");
                },
                Err(e) => Err(e)?
            }
            self.spi_wait(100).await?;
            self.cs.set_low();
            self.spi_wait(100).await?;
            self.cs.set_high();
        }
        Err(Error::Timeout)
    }

    async fn read_ocr_on_non_idle(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        defmt::info!("Reading OCR");
        let response = self.send_command::<ReadOcr>(ZeroArgument, Some(false), Some(8)).await?;
        defmt::info!("OCR decoded as {}", response);
        Ok(())
    }

    async fn on_insert(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        defmt::info!("Waiting for voltage to settle");
        Timer::after(Duration::from_millis(200)).await;
        defmt::info!("Putting SD into SPI mode");
        self.cs.set_high();
        self.spi_wait(100).await?;
        self.cs.set_low();
        self.spi_wait(100).await?;
        self.cs.set_high();

        self.reset().await?;
        self.select_voltage().await?;
        self.read_ocr_and_check_voltage().await?;
        self.send_operation_condition().await?;
        self.read_ocr_on_non_idle().await?;
        
        Ok(())
    }
```

For people who don't read Rust:

- Before any command I write 8 bytes of 0xFF
- I first send GO_IDLE_STATE (`40 00 00 00 00 95`) followed by SEND_IF_COND (`48 00 00 01 AA 87`)
- I check voltage by READ_OCR (`7A 00 00 00 00 FD`) to which card replies that it supports 2.7-3.6 voltage range
- I repeatedly call APP_CMD (`77 00 00 00 00 65`)/SEND_OP_COND with bit for SDHC support set (`69 40 00 00 00 77`) until I get non-IDLE state
- I check state by READ_OCR (`7a 00 00 00 00 fd`) but SSC bit is not set.

What am I doing wrong? Since the same happens in CircuitPython (size reported there is 128 MiB) I suspect the problem is with choice of components or something.

Comment: If the CCS is 0 then your card is a standard capacity card. Where did you buy the card? Are sure it's really a 32 gb card?

Comment: @nanash1 It's detected as 32 GiB by computer reader. Even if it was a counterfeit I would imagine they would present themselves as the same in both cases?

Comment: I'm not sure. The PC will use SDIO and not SPI. Have you tried to write a few gb to the card to confirm the capacity?

Comment: @nanash1 It's at least 2GiB card with VFAT. I stored 2 GiB randomly generated file, reinserted card and SHA matched.